# How much does air resistance affect the angular velocity of a golf ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, aerodynamics, drag, angular-velocity

I'm modeling the flight trajectory of a golf ball, and using angular velocity to calculate the [Magnus force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect).  Currently, I'm assuming angular velocity to be fixed throughout the ball's flight.

How accurate will this be?  How much will the angular velocity of the ball be affected by air resistance?

Comment: More on [Magnus effect](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+magnus).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very detailed analysis of the physics of spinning balls, torque and drag, in http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~mpersson/docs/AeroSphere_Persson.pdf

More simply, according to [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56799/26969), in the case of a sphere spinning *in place* the torque experienced is given by

$$
  \vec\tau = -8\pi R^3\eta\vec\Omega
$$

but that result seems to be valid only at very low Reynolds numbers - an assumption violated by most golf balls. So let's stick with the first reference.

From figure 3 of that reference we see roughly three regimes for the "torque coefficient" as a function of Reynolds number (note that the graph is labeled with Reynolds-Zahl number but I think that is an error as "Zahl" is the German word for "number"...):

[image]

The torque coefficient is related to the torque drag $M_{RD}$ by the equation

$$C_T = \frac{M_{RD}}{\frac12 \rho r^5 \omega^2}$$

Assuming that this evaluated to 0.02 (Reynolds number around 300,000), we can calculate the instantaneous torque on the golf ball, using typical dimensions: 
diameter 42 mm, mass 46 gram, assumed uniformly distributed. Typical [rate of rotation of a golf ball might be 3000 rpm](http://blog.trackmangolf.com/spin-rate/) (depends on type of ball and club... this is a "nominal" value) which gives $\omega = 2\pi * 50 \approx 300 s^{-1}$.

This makes the torque

$$\Gamma = 0.02 * 0.5 * 1.2 * 0.042^5 * 300 ^ 2 = 10^{-4} \mathrm{Nm}$$

If we assume the mass to be uniformly distributed, we can compute the moment of inertia

$$
I = \frac25 m r^2 = 3.2\cdot 10^{-5}\; \mathrm{kg m^2}
$$

Now we can see that the rate of change of the spin is

$$\frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{\Gamma}{I} \approx 3 s^{-2}$$

In other words, the golf ball will lose 1% of its spin for every second of flight.

Depending on the accuracy of your model, this may need taking into account. Obviously you would have to do the analysis more carefully - in particular, the dependence of drag on rate of rotation. Also, the dimples in the golf ball have significant impact on the drag; I did not have time to find references to better describe that.

Comment: An analysis can also be found at [this link](http://nothingnerdy.wikispaces.com/file/view/Flight%20of%20golf%20ball%20-%20sample%20EE.pdf) - there the rate of spin was assumed to be constant (but noted as a "assumption" that might be flawed), and indeed other sources of error most likely dominate.

Comment: This can't be all. Sometimes when I hit the ball, it will travel straight for the pin for about 75-100 yards when it reaches maximum height, then it takes the worst slice you've ever seen.

Comment: @LDC3 - indeed, there is much more to it. For one - if the ball is not perfectly symmetrical, it may precess while flying (rare, but could explain your mid-air slice); second - the air speed changes (significantly) which reduces the lift - but also makes small lateral forces more effective in changing the direction of the ball. I was just trying, in response to the question, to estimate the rate of change of rotation in flight - that's just a small piece of the golf puzzle.