# Terminal Velocity of a block falling in water

Tags: fluid-dynamics

So as part of a physics experiment I have to conduct for my grade 12 project, I decided to investigate the following question - "What effect does the mass of a cubic block of wood* (constant surface area, material, etc.) have on the terminal velocity it reaches in water?

The standard drag-force equation given every where is (CρAv^2)/2. I have a few questions -

1. Where does this equation come from? What is the derivation based on?
2. Will this equation work for my experimental model? to find the terminal velocity I would just need to equate the block's weight to the drag force. (FYI, the block is a hollow 7 cmx7cm wooden cube. I will be conducting the experiment in a large glass container - 140 cmx20 cmx20 cm)
3. How would I find the time and distance after which terminal  velocity is reached? because the drag force is varying as the velocity varies, and the velocity is varying as a function of weight and the drag force - how does one analyse this?
4. Does this equation account for the buoyance force? If not, Can i just incorporate it directly into my equations?

Thank you!

*I made a hollow wooden box, in which I am filling Iron filings to vary mass.

Comment: Search the Internet where there are many versions of the experimental details.

Comment: This may help - [Friction over a rotating ball under water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768014/37364)